# Routing for model that has an association from another module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to figure out a problem I'm having with generating paths, and what I need to put in my routes file.

At the moment I have the following:

```
class Car
  has_many :doors, class_name: 'Cars::Door'
end

module Cars
  class Door
  end
end
```

When attempting to render a simple form for the door, i.e

```
simple_form [@car, @car.doors.build]
```

I get the following error

```
undefined method 'car_cars_doors_path'
```

The above is pseudo code, so forgive any typos. Can someone tell me what I need to put in routes.rb to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Car model is already scoped under the module cars, you don't have to scope it again with car object in simple form

```
simple_form_for @car.doors.build
```

This would generate the path `cars_doors_path`. If you need car_doors_path, you will have to specify it explicitly

```
simple_for_for @car.doors.build, :url => car_doors_path
```

Comment: I don't want to specify the url manually every time, I was wondering if there was an automatic way of doing this via routes.

Answer (score 0):

```
simple_form_for [@car, @car.doors.build], url: car_doors_path(@car) do |f|
```

It works in my project.

Comment: Can you provide an exact example please?